# Altium shows little black blocks on my GND pads and tracks

Tags: altium

After many years of using altium designer this time I faced to new problem.

After updating the schematic to PCB document it shows all of my GND pads and tracks covered by little black blocks as shown in picture:

[image: PCB picture]

It's not my software problem because it shows other files correctly, also it's not about my rules because I've not changed them yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any chance you're using AD17? They introduced a feature which allows you to set a color for your nets in the schematic. This color is then transferred to the PCB and this is what you're seeing.
You might want to remove the color from the net in the schematic, transfer it to the PCB and it should be gone.

Alternatively, you can also set a net color in the PCB.